Win error 126 while trying to import aitextgen
So I am experimenting with AI and tried to import a gpt-2 model into Python so I can use it. I already ran
pip install aitextgen
pip install torch

And the file C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll exists.
Exception has occurred: OSError
[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\OfflineCoding\AI\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import aitextgen
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Note:
I tried reinstalling pytorch, it's still the same as before.
